# Specifying a specific route in an Express Router used with an array of routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The [Express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#path-examples) are clear about the fact that you can supply `app.use` with an array of routes for a particular piece of middleware.

They also describe how to split routers into separate files [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router).

But I can't see how to combine these two approaches.

### index.js

```
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
app.use(['/api/register', '/api/login'], authRoutes);
```

### ./routes/auth

```
router.route('/')
  .all((req, res) => res.send('responds to both routes'); // <- this works

router.route('/register') // <- But how can I specify a specific route?
  .all((req, res) => {
    res.send('The register route');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to do something like this

```
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
app.use('/api', authRoutes);


router.route(['/register', '/login']) .   // respond to both
  .all((req, res) => res.send('responds to both routes'); 

router.route('/register') // this is /api/register
  .all((req, res) => {
    res.send('The register route');
  });

router.route('/login') // this is /api/login
  .all((req, res) => {
    res.send('The login route');
  });
```

However there is something wrong with this logic , because your single routes `/register` and `/login` in auth file will never be called when you pass `/api/login` or `/api/register` they will go through the first array route. If you put the first route to the bottom then the array route respond to both route will be never called since it either goes to first /register route or 2nd /login route.

Comment: You've put the array in `router.route()`, but in my code the array is in `app.use`. Are you saying that these are equivalent?

Comment: actually no , `app.use` is a middleware , but route mounts middleware specific to that route. but if you are setting middle ware only for /resiter and /login , i don't see the difference between serving middleware at app or `/api` sub route.